The response content must be rendered before it can be accessed
I am trying to make the custom response format for that i have done below mentioned code
middleware
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException

class CustomResponseMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        from adminPanel.serializers import MyCustomException

        if not isinstance(response, Response):
            return response

        response.render()

        if 'data' in response.data:
            return response

        response_data = {
            'status': response.status_code,
            'message': 'Success',
            'error': False,
            'data': response.data,
            'error_message': None,
        }

        if isinstance(response, MyCustomException):
            error_message = response.detail.get('error_message', None)
            response_data = {
                'status': response.status_code,
                'message': 'Error',
                'error': True,
                'data': None,
                'error_message': error_message,
            }

        return Response(response_data, status=response.status_code)

in setting.py
'adminPanel.middleware.custom_response.CustomResponseMiddleware',

serializers.py
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username_or_email = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    access_token = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    refresh_token = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    user_type = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    request_source = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, default='mobile')

    def validate(self, data):
        username_or_email = data.get('username_or_email')
        password = data.get('password')

        if not username_or_email or not password:
            raise MyCustomException(detail={"error_message": "Must include 'username_or_email' and 'password'."}, status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        user = authenticate(
            request=self.context.get('request'), 
            username=username_or_email, 
            password=password
        )

        if user is None:
            raise MyCustomException(detail={"error_message": "Invalid username/email or password."}, status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        if not user.is_active:
            raise MyCustomException(detail={"error_message": "User is inactive."}, status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        if not user.email_verified:
            email_otp = ''.join([str(randint(0, 9)) for _ in range(6)])
            user.email_otp = email_otp
            user.save()
            send_registration_email.delay(
                'Welcome to Your Website',
                'email.html',
                {'code': email_otp},
                settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                [user.email],
            )
            raise MyCustomException(detail={"error_message": "Please verify your email first"}, status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        if not user.phone_verified:
            phone_otp = ''.join([str(randint(0, 9)) for _ in range(6)])
            user.phone_otp = phone_otp
            user.save()
            raise MyCustomException(detail={"error_message": "Phone number is not verified. Please verify it first"}, status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        request = self.context.get('request')
        if request is None:
            raise MyCustomException(detail={"error_message": "Request context is required."}, status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        request_source = request.headers.get('source', 'mobile')

        if request_source == 'mobile' and user.user_type != 'user':
            raise MyCustomException(detail={"error_message": "Only normal users can log in from mobile."}, status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        elif request_source == 'web' and user.user_type != 'seller':
            raise MyCustomException(detail={"error_message": "Only sellers can log in from the web portal."}, status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        if request_source == 'web':
            # Redirect to dashboard
            return {
                'status': status.HTTP_200_OK,
                'message': 'Redirect to dashboard',
                'error': False,
                'data': '/dashboard',
                'user_type': user.user_type,
            }
        else:
            # Return tokens for user
            return self._get_tokens_for_user(user, request_source)

    def _get_tokens_for_user(self, user, request_source):
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        access_token = str(refresh.access_token)
        refresh_token = str(refresh)

        return {
            'status':status.HTTP_200_OK,
            'message': 'Login successful',
            'error': False,
            'access_token': access_token,
            'refresh_token': refresh_token,
            'user_type': user.user_type,
        }


class MyCustomException(PermissionDenied):
    status_code = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    default_detail = "Custom Exception Message"
    default_code = 'invalid'

    def __init__(self, detail=None, status_code=None):
        if detail is not None:
            self.detail = detail
        else:
            self.detail = {"error_message": self.default_detail}
        if status_code is not None:
            self.status_code = status_code

    def render(self):
        # Render the exception content
        return Response(data=self.detail, status=self.status_code)

My View
class LoginView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            response_data = serializer.validated_data

            request_source = response_data.get('request_source')
            if request_source == 'web':
                return Response(
                    data=response_data,
                    status=status.HTTP_302_FOUND,  # HTTP status code for redirection
                    headers={'Location': response_data.get('redirect_url')}  # Redirection URL
                )

            return Response(data=response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except MyCustomException as exc:
            # If a custom exception is raised, return the error response
            return Response(data={"error_message": exc.detail}, status=exc.status_code)
        except Exception as e:
            # Handle other exceptions
            error_message = "An unexpected error occurred."
            return Response(data={"error_message": error_message}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

if response is success then i get my desired response like this
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Redirect to dashboard",
    "error": false,
    "data": "/dashboard",
    "user_type": "seller"
}

but if there is any error then i get this
ContentNotRenderedError at /api/login/
The response content must be rendered before it can be accessed.
Thank's for your help in advance
